# Command to clear taskwarrior server?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, sync, taskwarrior

During the debugging of this script https://github.com/a-t-0/PublicCodeLibrary/tree/master/AutomationAndSystems/Taskwarrior/CustomSort, I am trying to remove the task data from my taskd taskwarrior server.

There I am not aware of a taskwarrior forum and the https://botbot.me/freenode/taskwarrior/ is down. So I figured I would ask it here at Super User.

Initially, I misunderstood the meaning of the command `task sync init`. I thought it pushes the local tasks on the taskserver as being the complete list that should be on the taskserver. However that is an invalid assumption, in reality it just adds the tasks, as is stated here https://taskwarrior.org/docs/taskserver/sync.html. So the command in itself is not sufficient to clear the taskserver.

Hence I have also tried:

1. remove `backlog.data`, `completed.data`, `pending.data` and `undo.data` from `~/.task/`. And enter the command `sudo task sync init`.
2. remove `backlog.data`, `completed.data`, `pending.data` and `undo.data` from `~/.task/`. Recreate those files by creating a single task using command `task add task1`. Enter the command `sudo task sync init`.
3. Remove the taskwarrior server from ubuntu WSL 16.04 using command `apt-get remove taskd` and rebooting WSL Ubuntu 16.04 and repeating first step 1, then step 2. Both not effective.
4. Remove the taskwarrior server from ubuntu WSL 16.04 using command `apt-get purge taskd` and rebooting WSL Ubuntu 16.04 and repeating first step 1, then step 2. Both not effective. As suggested here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/187888/what-is-the-correct-way-to-completely-remove-an-application. followed by step 1 and step 2.
5. I updated to taskwarrior 2.6.0 to use the purge command on all tasks as: task purge, but it did not remove the tasks from the local taskwarrior, so it doesn't remove them from the taskserver either.

[image: Task purge did not delete the tasks from the local taskwarrior.]

A way to effectively clear the taskserver is to completely un-install the WSL Ubuntu, and re-install taskwarrior, taskwarrior server and the other software I run on the Ubuntu. As much as that is an excellent exercise in forcing me to think very well before I try another debugging test that corrupts the data, I am also eager to learn about the functioning of taskwarriors taskserver.

Therefore I wonder if someone knows the command(s) to clear the taskwarrior server from within Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

Task Warrior installs well on ubuntu but, I you must have installed task server to sync your tasks between computers. Well I just did that but, I'll also say it was involved. there is the git method of installing taskd. It goes like this.

- make a user twarrior and change to that user

```bsh
$ sudo add user twarrior
$ su twarrior
$ mkdir ~/opt
$ cd ~/opt
```

- git clone the server

```bsh
$ git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/GothenburgBitFactory/taskserver.git
```

Build the server ( you need some packages installed to build )

The build Process

dependencies needed

```bsh
sudo apt install g++
sudo apt install libgnutls28-dev
sudo apt install uuid-dev
sudo apt install cmake
sudo apt install gnutls-bin

# Then make build from the rep directory ~/opt/taskserver

cd $SOURCE
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=release .
make
sudo make install
```

- goto the ~/opt/taskserver/scripts folder and *run* repo with a setup script. It works.

*You should take caution and (avoid setting up any duplicate hostname or /etc/host aliasing). I forced my machine to read the hostname from the /etc/hostname record and it was also assigning it as an alias in /ect/hosts and then I setup a DNS server too, with different names... Obviously, though just one is enough. I prefer a DNS on your private network for name resolver.*

```bsh
$ cd ~/opt/taskserver/scripts/ && ./setup_server.bash
```

- you will need some info like domain address.

Some additional steps

- You add a user using `taskd add org "<ORGANIZATION>"` `taskd add user "<ORGANIZATION>" "<YOUR USERNAME>`
- this sets up the server directory with a uuid to stand in place of your name.
- You will also see your uuid of the user you set up
- changing to the repos pki directory you will see your user keys setup in the setup step
- you will do it right and do it again if you make mistakes

I think the setup takes care of the server configuration but, if you had any mistakes there is great documentation that discusses every bit of configuration settings although the commands you'll type are often just easiest typed not copy and pasted.
[[Task Warrior Server DOCS](https://gitpitch.com/GothenburgBitFactory/taskserver-setup#/)]

The server is

- you copy Your_Name.cert.pem Your_Name.key.pem and ca.cert.pem to your real user account ~/.task dir --- doing this will require sudo and chown the files to your real user:group
- check see if taskd is running `ps -leaf | grep taskd`
- it can be started if not with `taskdctl start` (do this as twarrior user).
- back in as your normal user run `task sync init` and (y)
- you should now be up and running.

Comment: thank you very much for your elaborate explanation! Perhaps I misunderstand your answer, though it appears to be a set of explicit instructions to install taskserver (TS). Whereas the question is about a set of commands to clear the TS. Do you mean your solution as: "delete TS from Ubuntu" and re-install TS from Ubuntu?

I think the purge command in taskwarrior(TW) 2.6.0 provides a solution, but I have not tested it on the initial problem yet. My current solution was automating the complete installation process of TW and TS.

Comment: Ok, so I think your still trying to figure out where on the computer does the "Server" store your data, and when you don't want it there anymore, like testing the setup, or testing extensions, how will you delete it. I looked in /var/taskd/ nothing is apparently transferred to that location. Maybe it just puts everything on the one computer on the next computer you connect with the same credentials. I have it on 3 systems I use and it syncs to all 3 so. It may just be Authentication and Merge conflict Service which all I need. It works great so far.